With wifi and mobile data off, iPhone still received and sent Whatsapp messages
A very strange thing happened this morning, my mobile data was off and Wifi was unconnected while travelling on a train. But I received multiple messages via WhatsApp. I was also able to send messages that were received but no images were sent (I tried to send a screenshot of connections being off but receiving messages). I thought it had randomly connected to a network but the Wifi said not connected in settings. After switching off Wifi (hence Wifi, Bluetooth and mobile data were all 'Off' in settings) I still was able to receive and send messages. The only connection was cellular, but no 4G/3G or Wifi.
The moment I turned on airplane mode this stopped, once I turned it back off I could no longer send or receive messages until I connected to a network again.
I have found this very strange, and cannot find in the Analytics any data relating to connections to networks made at this time (is this possible to see what network I was connected to at a specific time?).
The only logs in Analytics Data at this time was SiriSearchFeedback at the exact time when I started receiving messages without being connected to any network.
Does anyone have a logical explanation for data transfers without explicit connections?
Model: iPhone SE (2nd gen)
iOS: 17.4.1

switching between networks or with a weak signal, notifications for messages you received earlier might get delayed and pop up later

@Martin.s I understand this, except this was an ongoing conversation. And at some point all possible (to my knowledge) ways to receive messages were off, so this would not explain that. There was no signal (for wifi), this would've shown up if it were weak as a connection but there was none.
